# Google Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode - projection query and indexes

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I've read all the docs, but am struggling with this query in GCP Firestore in Datastore Mode:

`` SELECT id, title FROM `Book` WHERE author = 'Twain' ``

I've tried all the permutations of properties and indexes and where clauses that I can think of... What works:

`` SELECT id, title FROM `Book` ``

because I have created this **index.yaml** and built it with `gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml`

```
indexes:

- kind: Book
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: id
  - name: title
```

I can also

`` SELECT * FROM `Book` WHERE author = 'Twain' ``

because author is an indexed property of the Book entity.

I've tried adding author to the index (in addition to title and id), but Datastore still complains *"GQL Query error: Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query."*

What am I missing? The entity is quite large, and I just want to retrieve a list of the titles to populate the web page, not every property! I also don't want to retrieve the entire set of entities, since obviously only a few of them have been written by a particular author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the 'Developer Tools' in your favourite browser, you can see the full error returned to your query is:

`"no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Book\n  properties:\n  - name: author\n  - name: id\n  - name: title\n",`

Pretty printing that, we get:

```
- kind: Book
  properties:
  - name: author
  - name: id
  - name: title
```

Which is the expected index because the filtering happens on author, and the id and title fields are pulled from the index for your query.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. One KEY point is that the property that you use in the where clause must appear FIRST! The index.yaml you show will allow you to have a where clause like
```where author = 'Twain'``` but not ```where title = 'Othello'```

Comment: Another thing that was in the documentation that I overlooked was: any entity that is missing *any* of the properties in the index, will not be included. It doesn't show up in my example above, but it was a contributor to my inability to see the problem. (e.g., assume that there was also a property `cover` that linked to a picture, but only about 10% of the entities had this property. Only 10% of the entities will appear in the index - which makes sense if you think about it. If you want them all, then all entities must have a `cover` property with an empty value.)